# Enabled combobox controls looking disabled in windows 10?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, mfc, windows-10

I just upgraded to windows 10, and the majority of my software's combo boxes are greyed out, but still clickable. Is this normal? It's confusing for our users since they will think all the combo box controls are disabled.

I did a test with comboboxes and editbox, and it seems there is no longer a standard control color for "disabled" controls. That can be quite confusing for the user [image]

Comment: It's normal.  They'll get used to it.

Comment: @HansPassant I know I will get used to it too, but it's not very clear, and I personally hate the new style... :)

Comment: There is no getting used to chaos. Somehow MS has gotten toddlers from kindergarten and put them in charge of the Windows development team, or at least people who don't understand systematic thinking. I have no clue what persons are in charge of these chaos at MS, but they must have lots of fun seeing the world having no alternative then to accept it. Just my 4 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These colors are normal now. I have myself running Windows 8.1 and I don't see any difference to Windows 10.

If you prefer other styles, you can set them in your project, or do an owner-draw.

Comment: Sorry to necro, but where you say you can set the styles in your project, how would one do this? I don't particularly want to ownerdraw every combobox I ever use in DropDownList mode. It really is a shame microsoft don't offer a way to change the colour of this control the same as all other controls can be changed.